# I can not understand apache rewrite which use $1 in rewriteCond

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

for example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I　can not undertand the meaning of $1 in the RewriteCond.

If $1 appoint to (.*) of RewriteRule,so we can use like that in the RewriteCond?

Answer (score 0):

Yes `$1` corresponds to first matching group in your `RewriteRule`. This is usually done to prevent **infinite looping** (dreaded internal 500 error in Apache).

**PS:** This condition may not be necessary here since you already have `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` before it.

Comment: Using a capturing group reference will do nothing to prevent an infinite loop, anyone usually-using it for that purpose is mistaken.